# how to display subcategory in list page filter?

Tags: magento-1, layered-navigation, sidebar

I want to display the subcategories of selected category in list page.

ex:

```
level0:
     level1
     level1
     level1
         level2
         level2
level0
     level1
     level1
         level2
```

This is the basic structure of topmenu categories. I want the level1 and its respective level2 menus of selected level0 category to get displayed in the sidebar of list page as filter.

I have just tried it with the following code:

```
    <?php

$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$categories = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())

 ?>
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($categories) > 0): ?>

<div class="sidebar-block">
    <ul class="cat-list">
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
            <li class="category-li active">
             <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($category)  ?>"  >
                 <div class="main-cat" >  <?php echo $category->getName()?> </div>
                </a>

                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId()) ?>
                    <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                    <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <div class="sub-cat " style="display:none;">
                    <ul class="subcat-list">
                                <?php foreach ($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                            <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

And the level1 and level2 categories are getting displayed.
Here as am getting in for loop as subcategory of category, When I click the level1 category  form the filter, only its subcategory (ie) level2 is displayed in sidebar. I want level1 and level2 categories to be displayed when level0 or level1 categories are clicked. When Level2 category is clicked the parent categories need not be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to display the `level1` and `level2` categories in list page when `level0` and `level1` categories are slected from the topmenu.

```
    <div class="layered-view">     

<?php
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$categories = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())     

 ?>
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if($category->getLevel() == 2): ?>
<?php if (count($categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul id="level1" class="category">

        <?php foreach($categories as $_category): ?>


            <li class="level1 inactive">

                <a href= "<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>" > 
                    <div class="main-cat" ><?php echo $_category->getName() ?> </div>
                </a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>

                    <ul id="level2" style="display:none;">
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li class="level2 inactive">
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($category->getLevel() == 3): ?>

<?php 
$parentId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getParentCategory()->getId();
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId)->getChildrenCategories(); ?>
<?php if (count($cats) > 0): ?>
    <ul id="level1" class="category">
        <?php foreach ($cats as $cat): ?>
            <li class="level1 inactive" >
                <a href= "<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($cat) ?>" >
                    <div class="main-cat-1" ><?php echo $cat->getName() ?> </div>
                </a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <ul id="level2" style="display:none;">
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li class="level2 inactive" >
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please update your filter like this:

```
$category  = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();

$parentIds = $category->getParentIds();
$exclParentIds = array(1, Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
$childIds = $category->getChildren();
$inclIds = array_diff(array_merge($parentIds, $childIds), $exclParentIds);
if ($category->getParentId() > 1) {
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->addIdFilter($inclIds);
} else {

    $category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren());
}
```

Basically what we are doing here is, combining all category parent ids (excluding default root id and store root id) and children category ids and apply it to `addIdFilter()`

Comment: should I replace first two lines of my code with urs? and it is displaying as syntax error in the above code

Comment: now please try. syntax error fixed. yes you need to replace first two line with this.

Comment: When I pasted this code the filter has disappeared as whole.

Comment: @Ramya can you try now. sorry it is not a tested code. But I give you the idea.

Comment: No it is not working @Rajeev. The filter is disappearing. Is there anyway other way to  get level1 and level2 categories and display it in layered navigation. Please guide me if you know any alternative way.